# Deploying multiple versions of static folders on a single PCF instance app

Tags: cloud-foundry, pcf

Is there any possibility to keep older directories intact while pushing static application files on PCF?

For example I have deployed 2 folders V1 & latest on PCF,
On next deployment I will push "V2" & "latest" & expectation is "V1" shouldn't be deleted, "latest" should be overridden & "V2 should be deployed!

[image]

Comment: That's not how CF works at all; you aren't adding files to a folder, you're building and deploying a completely new droplet. Maybe run through https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/index.html to get a better idea of how the platform works.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work the way you're thinking about it, but I think you can achieve the end result you want. Here's what I would suggest.

Whatever you have locally & push will be your app. Thus if you want V1 + Latest, then you need to push V1 + Latest. If you want V1 + V2 + Latest, then you push all three of those. If you want V1 + V2 + V3 + Latest, then that's what you push.

What you push is what you'll end up with in your app.

Ex:

Folders:

```
app/
  v1/
  latest/
```

Run `cf push my-cool-app` from `app/` and you'll end up with v1 + latest being served up.

Folders:

```
app/
  v1/
  v2/
  v3/
  latest/
```

Run `cf push my-cool-app` from `app/` and you'll end up with v1 + v2 + v3 + latest being served up.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is something we thought of but not the feasible/scalable solution for us as our builds are complex & frequent. Building multiple versions at each deployment will be very heavy!!

Comment: I'm not sure you have a lot of choice. As @jonrsharpe pointed out in a comment, what you're asking for is simply not possible. You cannot retain state from one push to the next. If this solution doesn't work for you, then you're going to need to go back to the drawing board and completely rethink what you're trying to do.